# for in twig templates of drupal is behaving strangely

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am trying to show only upcoming events from a list of events. Below is how I have tried to display.

```
<div class="row">
    {% for item in items %}
        {% if item.content['#node'].field_event_type.getValue()|first.value == 'upcoming' %}
            <div class="col">{{item.content}}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But the output rendering is, the second event is displaying after the row div like below. I don't understand how this is happening as the for loop is inside the row div

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col"> content </div>
</div><div class="col"> content </div>
```

Expected output

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col"> content </div>
  <div class="col"> content </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Twig does lots of things:

- loading (open your Twig content)
- parsing (create a parse tree from your Twig content)
- compiling (browse that tree to create a php file)
- caching (store the php file somewhere to avoid recompile it next time)
- executing (execute the generated php file)

When a `{% for %}` is detected during parsing, Twig calls the token parser recursively until it finds `{% endfor %}` and builds a token tree. In your case, it would look like:

```
root
 |
 --- string
 |
 --- for
 |   |
 |    --- if
 |        |
 |        --- string
 |
 --- string
```

Then, Twig compiler crosses over that tree recursively and generates the corresponding php code. In that way, the following Twig loop:

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
Value = {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

Compiles to this in PHP:

```
// line 1
$context['_parent'] = $context;
$context['_seq'] = twig_ensure_traversable(range(1, 5));
foreach ($context['_seq'] as $context["_key"] => $context["i"]) {
    // line 2
    echo "Value = ";
    echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $context["i"], "html", null, true);
}
$_parent = $context['_parent'];
unset($context['_seq'], $context['_iterated'], $context['_key'], $context['i'], $context['_parent'], $context['loop']);
$context = array_intersect_key($context, $_parent) + $_parent;
```

As you can see, a `{% for %}` is no more than a simple `foreach` and as Twig tokens are stored into a tree, it is by design not possible to display contents located below a pair of open/close tags.

The only possibility I can see is that one of the tag you're using in Twig is playing with output buffering, and one of the methods you're using in your loop breaks the ob stack (like a `ob_get_clean()` without any `ob_start()` for example, that have been open previously).

My advice is to grep your twig file name into your cache directory (eg: `grep -Ri 'test.twig' cache/`) in order to see that file compiled to PHP, to understand exactly what it does, and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering your content in twig, filter the results in your Drupal view.

In the "filter criteria" on your view, select the field_event_type field and set it "is equal to" and select/add 'upcoming' as the option.

If you filter in the view, you don't have to mess with the twig template.